# New Feature - Update Responses

Tags: google-classroom

We have an internal database ID for each course we have.  When using the batch function to create courses, the returned information doesn’t not give us any way to get this ID back so we cannot update our database and let it know that the course has been created.

Also updating the deletion response for the same reason would also be handy.

The response for a batch of deletes looks like:

```
--batch_123456
{}
--batch_123456
--batch_123456
{}
--batch_123456
--batch_123456
{}
--batch_123456
```

If they are all successful then it's not really a problem, but if something goes wrong then it's impossible to tell which ones were deleted and which ones were not deleted, because according to the API:

" The server may perform your calls in any order. Don't count on their being executed in the order in which you specified them."

A simple message that said "course #123 has been deleted" would be very helpful.  That way I could program the callback code to update the database using the ID

For the course creation the response looks like:

```
--batch_123456
{
"id": "208571459",
"name": "***",
"section": "***",
"ownerId": "123456",
"creationTime": "2015-09-14T13:13:59.622Z",
"updateTime": "2015-09-14T13:14:02.820Z",
"enrollmentCode": "***",
"courseState": "PROVISIONED",
"alternateLink": "***"
}
--batch_123456
```

I only put in one response to save space.  The ID is the new GoogleID of the course, the ID we actually send in which corresponds to the records in our DB does not get returned.  So we have to use a combination of other data (ownerID + name) to get the record and update it, but this is not ideal and may not work fro everyone.  Again adding in all of the information that get's sent into the response would be very helpful so we can use the callback properly.

I also want to add the more useful specific information should also be added to all error messages.  In fact every batch response should have some sort of ID, that way the callback functions can be more useful.

Comment: Could you share a response example you are getting from the batch operation?

Comment: Better yet, share your code. Very hard to troubleshoot without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: Hey Jay, the API is working exactly as expected, I'm asking for an update to the API, not help trouble shooting, but the offer to help is very much appreciated.

Comment: just to clarify, when making the request to create a course, you send the ID you generated in your Database, correct?  and, are you sending this ID in the id field? o how are you sending it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned briefly in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses), you can pass an alias into `Courses.id` when creating a course to assign an alias to a course as you create it. The alias can include your internal identifier for the course and can be used in future requests.

Alternatively, each request in a batch can be assigned a unique `Content-ID` header, which will be returned in the response. Many client libraries provide built-in support for setting and getting these IDs.

Comment: The alias id would probably be OK, but we already have a very labor intensive process running. With 10,000 courses and 50,000 students, syncing all that data takes a while, adding in a extra set of course reads is not ideal and inefficient.

Comment: The Conent-Id is a great idea any ideas on how to do with the Classroom API?

Comment: Are you using a client library, or making these HTTP requests directly?

Comment: I'm using the Google Classroom API V1 for .net.

Comment: We're actually looking into that same question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637718/how-to-set-the-content-id-in-a-goolge-classroom-api-v1-request