# How to set the content-id in a Google Classroom API V1 request

Tags: c#, google-classroom

I'm creating a lot of batched requests and I want to keep track of which ones are successful and which ones error.  I'm using all kinds of different requests with the Google Classroom API V1.

I want to set the content-ID to a unique value and reference it in the callbacks.  Any help would be appreciated, especially in C#.

Here is a sample for adding a course deletion to a batch request:

```
requests[CurrentBatch].Queue<GoogleCourse>(serviceCredential.Service.Courses.Delete(course.Id), (content, error, i, message) =>
            {

                if (content != null)
                {
                    //add the classroom 
                    GoogleClassroom.DAL.Datamodule.SaveGoogleCourseIdByNameAndUser(content.Id, content.Name, content.OwnerId);
                    log.Write("Successfully Added\n");
                }
                if (error != null)
                {
                    log.Write("error:" + error.ToString() + "\n");
                }
                if (message != null)
                {
                    log.Write("message:" + message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString() + "\n");
                }

            });
```

Comment: I have tried reading the API documentation and looking at the Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.ClassroomService and Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.CoursesResource.CreateRequest objects to see if there were any setting or methods I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the .NET client doesn't provide an easy way to set the Content-ID header for specific request in the batch. I've tried a few methods to manually set the Content-ID header but without success. The best alternative at the moment is to use the index of the request / response to link them together, and the index is passed into the callback handler as the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Is the index the value they are returned or the value they are sent?   Because the order you send them is not always the order they are returned in, I have seen this and it specifically says that in the API.  

Also when your send thousands of batches requests asynchronously its not super easy to keep track of which batch requests callback you are actually in.

Comment: The documentation correctly mentions that the order the requests are not guaranteed to _execute_ in order, but the results in a batch response will always be in the same order as the requests when they were queued. I understand that using the order is not as good as using Content-ID, and I encourage you to open a feature request on [library's GitHub project](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client), or even implement it yourself and send a pull request.

Comment: that's great that I can use the Index!  Do you have any idea on how I can link a response to the Batch from it's callback method?