# Google classroom api doesn't return the alias when a course is created

Tags: google-classroom

Background: We currently have a database with every course, teacher and student in our school board.  I am basically trying to build a system to sync this with our Google Classroom environment, so every teacher will have their courses, students will be enrolled ect.

Problem: We have over 8000 courses to create and want to use the batch system or at least create them asynchronously.  We pass our internal unique course ID in the create call through the alias.  However in the callback method this value is not passed back.  This means we have no way of linking the google unique ID to ours, and no way of knowing if something goes wrong, which courses were not created.

Example: I want to create 5 courses with the following ids:
1234
1235
1236
1237
1238

So I create a batch request and the call back gets called 5 times. The data in the call back does not contain the IDs I sent in though if only contains the google IDs:

9876
9875
Error
9873
9872

The API specifically mentions that the order cannot be trusted.  So how can I tell which google ID belong to which course and how can I tell witch course had the error?

Comment: Current Work arounds:
- put the ID in the description field
- create 1 course at a time synchronously (would take forever for us)

Comment: I am aware that I can probably check afterwards by using the passing the alias in a simple get call, but I can't do that in bathes either for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with courses you can pass in your wanted Alias with the course creation.

We do a similar thing at leveldata (Managing 10k+ courses is normal for us), for course creation we create them one at a time. There's threading and other things you could do to speed this up, but in reality classes don't change that often so as long as the initial run goes and creates them all in a long run (30-90 hrs with 10k courses) you should be good to go.

Looks like you already asked this question here [New Feature - Update Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531682/new-feature-update-responses)

I do agree batch adds should come back with course information, but this is the workaround we have.